# EPPLUS: Border in range

Tags: c#, epplus

I try to set border around range or cell but seems that i'm stuck. 
I have read almost all topic and didn't find solutions...

```
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange Rng = workSheet.Range[workSheet.Cells[1, 1], workSheet.Cells[2, 2]];
        Rng.Style.Border.BorderAround(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);

workSheet.Cells[1,1].BorderAround2(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
```

Both solutints dont work.

Answer (score 4):

Ver.: 4.5.2.1. On version 4.5 there is no **Range** in the worksheet, but **Cells** can achieve this.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
//...
    using (var range = workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 2, 2])
    {
        range.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

another option, example code:

```
worksheet.Cells["D16:AH23"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
worksheet.Cells["D16:AH23"].Style.Border.Top.Style =ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
worksheet.Cells["D16:AH23"].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
worksheet.Cells["D16:AH23"].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
```